# Counting of shortest sequences of flips in pancake sorting

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, optimization, multiprocessing

Now, finding the shortest sequence of flips in [pancake sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting) is alone NP-hard, yet I'd like to find each and all of them, and count them.

Meaning for each permutation I'd like to find all the sequences of prefix reversals that restores the identity but not longer than the shortest one.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from math import factorial
import itertools

from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Manager, Pool

import numpy
import scipy.sparse

def flip(x, value):
    return tuple(value[:x][::-1] + value[x:])

def rank(perm):
    n = len(perm)
    fact = factorial(n)
    r = 0
    for i in range(n):
        fact //= n - i
        r += len([x for x in perm[i:] if x < perm[i]]) * fact
    return r

def unrank(i, items):
    its = items[:]
    perm = []
    n = len(items)
    fact = factorial(n)
    r = i % fact
    while its:
        fact //= n
        c, r = divmod(r, fact)
        perm.append(its.pop(c))
        n -= 1
    return tuple(perm)

def get_colex_row(r, n, _fact):
    row = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((
        1, _fact[n - 1]), dtype=numpy.int8)
    perm = unrank(r, [i for i in range(n)])
    for i in range(n):
        column = r - r % _fact[i] + rank(perm[:-i - 2:-1])
        row[0, column] = i + 1
    return row

def get_colex_matrix(n):
    fact = [factorial(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    m = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(
            (fact[n - 1], fact[n - 1]), dtype=numpy.int8)
    items = [_ for _ in range(1, n + 1)]

    for r in range(fact[n - 1]):
        row = get_colex_row(r, n, fact)
        m[r] = row
    return m

def get_distance(n, items):
    nfact = factorial(n)
    stack = {unrank(i, items) for i in range(nfact)}
    m = get_colex_matrix(n)
    distance = {unrank(nfact - 1, items)[::-1] : 0}
    new_distance = {nfact - 1}
    d = 0
    while distance.keys() != stack:
        new_new_distance = set()
        d += 1
        for visiting in new_distance:
            for i in range(2, n + 1):
                key_index = m[visiting].tolist().index(i)
                key = unrank(key_index, items)[::-1]
                if key not in distance:
                    distance[key] = d
                    new_new_distance.add(key_index)
        new_distance = new_new_distance
    return distance

def get_paths_serial(items):
    n = len(items)
    nfact = factorial(n)
    stack = {unrank(i, items) for i in range(nfact)}
    m = get_colex_matrix(n)
    distance = {unrank(nfact - 1, items)[::-1]: {()}}
    new_distance = {nfact - 1}
    while distance.keys() != stack:
        new_new_distance = set()
        for visiting_index in new_distance:
            for i in range(2, n + 1):
                key_index = m[visiting_index].tolist().index(i)
                key = unrank(key_index, items)[::-1]
                visiting = unrank(visiting_index, items)[::-1]
                paths = distance[visiting]

                prev_sample = next(iter(paths))

                if key not in distance:
                    distance[key] = {path + (i,) for path in paths}
                    new_new_distance.add(key_index)
                else:
                    curr_sample = next(iter(distance[key]))
                    if len(prev_sample) + 1 < len(curr_sample):
                        print("Shouldn't happen!")
                        distance[key] = {path + (i,) for path in paths}
                    elif len(prev_sample) + 1 == len(curr_sample):
                        distance[key] |= {path + (i,) for path in paths}
                    else:
                        # not relevant
                        pass
        new_distance = new_new_distance
    return distance

def _worker(ns, index):
    row = get_colex_row(index, ns.n, ns.fact).toarray().tolist()[0]
    visiting = unrank(index, ns.items)[::-1]
    paths = ns.distance[visiting]
    prev_sample = next(iter(paths))
    out = {}
    my_new_distance = set()
    for i in range(2, ns.n + 1):
        key_index = row.index(i)
        key = unrank(key_index, ns.items)[::-1]
        if key not in ns.distance:
            out[key] = {path + (i,) for path in paths}
            my_new_distance.add(key_index)
        else:
            curr_sample = next(iter(ns.distance[key]))
            if len(prev_sample) + 1 < len(curr_sample):
                print("Shouldn't happen!")
                out[key] = {path + (i,) for path in paths}
            elif len(prev_sample) + 1 == len(curr_sample):
                out[key].update(path + (i,) for path in paths)
    return my_new_distance, out

def get_paths_parallel(items):
    n = len(items)
    fact = [factorial(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    distance = {unrank(fact[n - 1] - 1, items)[::-1]: {()}}
    stack = {unrank(i, items) for i in range(fact[n - 1])}
    already_visited = set()
    visiting = {fact[n - 1] - 1}
    mgr = Manager()

    namespace = mgr.Namespace()

    namespace.fact = fact
    namespace.distance = distance
    namespace.items = items
    namespace.n = n

    with Pool(2 * cpu_count()) as pool:
        while distance.keys() != stack:
            result = pool.starmap(_worker, ((namespace, job)
                    for job in visiting))

            visiting = set()
            for next_to_visit, visited in result:
                visiting |= next_to_visit
                for k, v in visited.items():
                    if k in distance:
                        distance[k] |= v
                    else:
                        distance[k] = v
            visiting -= already_visited
            already_visited |= visiting
            namespace.distance = distance
    return distance

def colex(value, other):
    for i in range(len(value) - 1, 0, -1):
        if value[i] == other[i]:
            continue
        return value[i] > other[i]
    return False

def ordered_by(order_cmp):
    'Convert a cmp= function into a key= function'
    if order_cmp is None:
        return None

    class K(object):
        def __init__(self, obj):
            self.value = obj
        def __gt__(self, other):
            if len(self.value) != len(other.value):
                assert "Not the same length"
            return order_cmp(self.value, other.value)
    return K

def get_ordered(n, order):
    return sorted(itertools.permutations(range(1, n + 1)),
                  key=ordered_by(order))


def get_matrix(n, order=None):
    stack = get_ordered(n, order)
    m = numpy.zeros((len(stack), len(stack)), numpy.int8)
    for i,s in enumerate(stack):
         for x in range(1, n + 1):
             m[i, stack.index(flip(x, s))] = x
    return m
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but `get_paths_parallel` runs slower than `get_paths_serial`, please help!

I really should (and probably will soon) document my code better.

So for the time being, I'll say a few additional words:

It uses co-lexicographic ordering to rank the permutations and to find the indices in the adjacency matrix. Where I store the length of the flip that transforms the permutations, e.g. **A**(*i,j*) = *k* if performing a *k* length prefix reversal on the permutation with rank *i* results the ranked *j* permutation. In order to save on memory instead of storing the whole matrix I generate the rows on demand and limit the access by excluding already visited ones also I'm using `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` for the same reason.

Other than these it's simply floods the graph till all permutations are reached.

There are some functions that doesn't use all or any of the consideration above like `get_matrix`, but presented only to validate that others, like `get_colex_matrix` are working as intended.

I'm creating the `key` function in a little bit convoluted manner, but that's just because I've tried other sorting before I've settled on co-lex.

Comment: Yes the answer it gives is valid, but I'm definitely doing something wrong in parallelization.

Comment: The problem seems illdefiend. There is an infinite number of sequences of possible flips which sort the pile.

Comment: True, but finite of them has infimum length. I'm looking for only for shortest subset of those, e.g. dfbeac and ecfadb can be sorted at least by 7 flips, but there's 22 possible sequence of them, while to sort acfdbe there's a single sequence that does it in 6 flips.

Answer (score 0):

Using `multiprocessing.Manager` to share data between processes makes them slow down.

Solution is to copy the needed data into each process's memory space (passing them as argument) or to use global variables for them.

Also using `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` is overkill, `dict` would do.

*I'll grab the literature I've found on the subject and link it hare later.*